# Dynamic TailwindCSS class is not working properly

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

Considering my code:

```
<template>
<section
    class="bg-gradient-to-br h-40"
    :class="
      'from-palettes-' +
      palette +
      '-primary to-palettes-' +
      palette +
      '-secondary'
    "
  >
    Topbar
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
      palette: "green-dark",
    };
  },

  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And my tailwind file:

```
extend: {
      colors: {
        palettes: {
          "green-dark": {
            primary: "#57876E", //dark color
            secondary: "#92BFA8", //light color
            gray: "#333453",
            accent: "#f8f2f2", //slight offset from white
            white: "#FAF9FA",
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Color is not loaded. When I check the console there are no errors, when I check source code, the class name is applied as it should. The corresponding class is however not found/applied. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is
> that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings
> in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names
> together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate
> the corresponding CSS.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names